# Powershell cast text to DateTime object

Tags: powershell, datetime

My code is a function in a module. Part of my report needs to sort the output by First Detected in reverse order.

My code:

```
function Run-PxReport($p) {
    switch ($p)
    {
        P1 {$template_id = 2074495}
        P2 {$template_id = 2075996}
        P3 {$template_id = 2075998}
        P4 {$template_id = 2075999}
        default {"The template ID could not be determined"}
        }
    # Download report in csv
    Write-Host ("-" * 60)
    Write-Host "Generating $p report. Please wait...`r`n"
    $launchReport = ([xml](curl.exe -sS -u username:password -H 'X-Requested-With:QualysApiExplorer' 'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/report/' -d "action=launch&template_id=$template_id&report_title=$p&output_format=csv"))
    $reportID = $launchReport.SelectNodes("//SIMPLE_RETURN/RESPONSE/ITEM_LIST/ITEM/VALUE").InnerText
    do{
    Start-Sleep -s 15
    $searchReport = ([xml](curl.exe -sS -u username:password -H 'X-Requested-With:QualysApiExplorer' 'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/report/' -d "action=list&id=$reportID"))
    $reportStatus = ($searchReport.REPORT_LIST_OUTPUT.RESPONSE.REPORT_LIST.REPORT | ? {$_.ID -eq $reportID}).STATUS.STATE
    } until($reportStatus -eq "Finished")
    curl.exe -sS -u username:password -H 'X-Requested-With:QualysApiExplorer' 'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/report/' -d "action=fetch&id=$reportID" > .\report.csv
    #clean up line breaks between quotes
    gc .\report.csv | Out-String | % {$_.replace(",`r",",").replace(",`n",",") } | Set-Content .\report.csv
    # Need to find number of rows to skip when importing csv to find end of interesting data.
    $reportContent = Get-Content .\report.csv
    # Need to get the number for "Hosts Matching Filters" on line 6.
    $line = $reportContent | select -first 1 -skip 5
    $totalHosts = $line.Split(",")[3]
    $intHosts = [int]$totalHosts.Replace("`"","")
    $skip = $intHosts + 14
    # Import-CSV, select-object to get only interesting columns.
    $csvData = Get-Content -Path .\report.csv | Select-Object -Skip $skip | ConvertFrom-Csv
    # Output totals of each severity 3,4,5.
    $severity5 = ($csvData | where {$_.Severity -eq 5}).Count
    $severity4 = ($csvData | where {$_.Severity -eq 4}).Count
    $severity3 = ($csvData | where {$_.Severity -eq 3}).Count
    $totalPx = ($severity3 + $severity4 + $severity5)
    # Output total Px.
    Write-Host "Total $p count:    $totalPx"
    Write-Host "Severity 5 total:  $severity5"
    Write-Host "Severity 4 total:  $severity4"
    Write-Host "Severity 3 total:  $severity3"
    # Top 10 most severe vulnerabilities
    Write-Host "`r`nTop 10 most severe vulnerabilities:"
    $toptenseverity = $csvData | select Severity, Title -Unique | sort Severity -Descending | select -First 11
    Write-Output $toptenseverity | Format-Table
    # Top 10 most common vulnerabilities:
    Write-Host "`r`nTop 10 most common vulnerabilities:"
    $toptencommon = $csvData | Group-Object Title | sort Count -Descending | select -First 10 | select Count, Name
    $toptencommon
    Write-Host "`r`nLatest vulnerabilities:"
    $new = $csvData | where {$_.Severity -ge 3} | sort 'First Detected' -Descending | select -First 50 | select IP,Title,'First Detected'
    Write-Output $new | Format-Table
    $deleteReport = ([xml](curl.exe -sS -u username:password -H 'X-Requested-With:QualysApiExplorer' 'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/report/' -d "action=delete&id=$reportID"))
}
```

I need to sort the output by "FirstDetected" in -Descending order.

My Script Output:

```
IP             Title                                                                     First Detected     
--             -----                                                                     --------------     
127.0.0.1   SSL/TLS use of weak RC4 cipher                                            12/29/2013 07:09:19
127.0.0.1   SSL/TLS use of weak RC4 cipher                                            12/29/2016 07:09:19
```

This is my CSV file (edited)

```
    "P1 - 20170624","06/24/2017 at 08:43:30 (GMT-0400)"
"Company Name","123 Main St.",,"Some Town","State","United States of America","12345"
"First Last","username","Manager"

"Asset Groups","IPs","Active Hosts","Hosts Matching Filters","Trend Analysis","Date Range","Asset Tags"
"NONE","NONE","393","134","Latest vulnerability data","12/31/1998 - 06/24/2017","Included(any): All External IP (xxx);
Excluded(any);"

"Total Vulnerabilities","Avg Security Risk","Business Risk"
"346","3.0","17/100"

"IP","Total Vulnerabilities","Security Risk"
"127.0.0.1","2","3.0"


"IP","DNS","NetBIOS","Tracking Method","OS","IP Status","QID","Title","Vuln Status","Type","Severity","Port","Protocol","FQDN","SSL","First Detected","Last Detected","Times Detected","Date Last Fixed","CVE ID","Vendor Reference","Bugtraq ID","CVSS","CVSS Base","CVSS Temporal","CVSS Environment","CVSS3","CVSS3 Base","CVSS3 Temporal","Threat","Impact","Exploitability","PCI Vuln","Ticket State","Instance","Category","Associated Tags"
"127.0.0.1","blah.blah.com",,"IP","Windows 2008 R2 / Windows 7","host scanned, found vuln","150161","Session Cookie Does Not Contain the ""Secure"" Attribute","Re-Opened","Vuln","3","80","tcp",,,"01/08/2017 10:39:32","06/18/2017 09:39:31","24","06/11/2017 21:08:29",,,,,"0 (AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:N)","0 (E:F/RL:W/RC:C)","Asset Group: -, Collateral Damage Potential:  -, Target Distribution: -, Confidentiality Requirement: -, Integrity Requirement: -, Availability Requirement: -",,,,"The session cookie does not contain the ""secure"" attribute","Session Cookies with ""secure"" attribute are only permitted to be sent via HTTPS. Session cookies sent via HTTP expose users to sniffing attacks that could lead to user impersonation or account compromise",,"no",,,"Web Application","All External, Windows"
"127.0.0.1","blah.blah.com",,"IP",,"host scanned, found vuln","38657","Birthday attacks against TLS ciphers with 64bit block size vulnerability (Sweet32)","Active","Vuln","3","443","tcp",,"over ssl","04/02/2017 10:31:19","06/24/2017 04:09:03","21",,"CVE-2016-2183",,"92630, 95568",,"5 (AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N)","4.3 (E:POC/RL:W/RC:C)","Asset Group: -, Collateral Damage Potential:  -, Target Distribution: -, Confidentiality Requirement: -, Integrity Requirement: -, Availability Requirement: -","4.9","5.3","4.9","Legacy block ciphers having block size of 64 bits are vulnerable to a practical collision attack when used in CBC mode. 
All versions of SSL/TLS protocol support cipher suites which use DES or 3DES as the symmetric encryption cipher are affected.","Remote attackers can obtain cleartext data via a birthday attack against a long-duration encrypted session.",,"no","Open",,"General remote services","All External, All External IP (xxx)"
"127.0.0.1","blah.blah.com",,"IP",,"host scanned, found vuln","38628","SSL/TLS Server supports TLSv1.0","Active","Vuln","3","443","tcp",,"over ssl","07/10/2016 08:00:17","06/24/2017 04:09:03","59",,,,,,"2.6 (AV:N/AC:H/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N)","2.3 (E:F/RL:W/RC:C)","Asset Group: -, Collateral Damage Potential:  -, Target Distribution: -, Confidentiality Requirement: -, Integrity Requirement: -, Availability Requirement: -","0","0","0","TLS is capable of using a multitude of ciphers (algorithms) to create the public and private key pairs. 
For example if TLSv1.0 uses either the RC4 stream cipher, or a block cipher in CBC mode. 
RC4 is known to have biases and the block cipher in CBC mode is vulnerable to the POODLE attack. 

TLSv1.0, if configured to use the same cipher suites as SSLv3, includes a means by which a TLS implementation can downgrade the connection to SSL v3.0, thus weakening security. 

",,"yes","Open",,"General remote services","All External, All External IP (xxx)"
```

Comment: Can you paste a few rows so we can see what the source data looks like?

Comment: Isn't there an `Import-Csv` in PowerShell?

Comment: I can't use Import-Csv for reasons already stated.

Comment: I added example csv to my post.

Comment: Can you please add some code where you convert on import, and where you need to use the value? What is in the "FirstDetected" column _before_ you attempt to cast? You're probably after `ParseExact`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a technique called a calculated property, which lets us pick certain properties out from the pipeline (previous commands) and then calculate a new value.

First, I copied your CSV and guessed that you probably omitted the first 8 or ten lines or so, so I started with the row that begins with `"IP","DNS","NetBIOS",` and saved it in `$i`.

```
$i | convertfrom-csv | select IP,Severity, Title,@{Name=‘First Detected‘;Expression={$_.'First Detected' -as [DateTime]}}
```

When this completed, I get the normal output I expect, and I can format based on date time too!

```
IP        Severity Title                                                                              First     
                                                                                                      Detected  
--        -------- -----                                                                              ----------
127.0.0.1 3        Session Cookie Does Not Contain the "Secure" Attribute                             1/8/201...
127.0.0.1 3        Birthday attacks against TLS ciphers with 64bit block size vulnerability (Sweet32) 4/2/201...
127.0.0.1 3        SSL/TLS Server supports TLSv1.0                                                    7/10/20...



PS C:\git> $outp | where 'First Detected' -ge (get-date '04/01/2017')

IP        Severity Title                                                                              First     
                                                                                                      Detected  
--        -------- -----                                                                              ----------
127.0.0.1 3        Birthday attacks against TLS ciphers with 64bit block size vulnerability (Sweet32) 4/2/201...
```